# Explaining Wireframes to Remote Clients Sent via Email?

Tags: wireframe, client

What is the best way to explain your wireframes to, in my case, overseas clients when you send them via email?

In this scenario my client is the user and I want to help him understand my process so that he is not confused when he sees the design. Would it make sense to explain the wireframes in the email itself or should it be done in a separate document?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Project Management Communication Issues, rather than UX.

Comment: I think this could be UX related actually. Because wire framing is apart of the UX profession, and annotating could be too (at least it was for me for a long time)

Comment: This is completely UX related question, its just not technical. In this scenario my client is the user and I want to help him understand my process better so that he is not confused when he sees the design.

Comment: Its a good UX question.  I've had to do this.  And as noted below I did quite a lot of talking it through on the phone as well.

Comment: Having to explain your wireframes with annotations is a funny thing to do as a UX professional.  Totally necessary, but it seems like it shouldn't be :).

Comment: @ChrisAplin IMHO, wireframes is a language that is mostly spoken by UX folks and (ideally) those developing. I actually think it's a burden for clients to have to learn a new language when they only care about the final output. Granted, the realities mean they often do need to learn the language, so it only makes sense that we're there to help translate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever I create a wireframe document, I make enough space on the right for annotations. Annotations are really nice so you can explain what an element is and what it could do in certain scenarios.

Here shows what I did for a document I prepared for a client:
[image]

You can also use that right side to show different states of the element (like on hovers, on active, when something happens, etc.)

Just make sure to also meet up with the clients on Skype/phone if you want to elaborate further on anything.

Answer (score 0):

Back in my consulting days, I used this preamble before presenting or sending over any wireframes.

> Informs design and guides development by illustrating the navigation,
>   content  structure and functionality. Interaction specifications are
>   included to define  fundamental user interactions.

Comment: I feel like this preamble does not help in a significant number of cases. If I didn't know what you are trying to say from the question I would not understand it. May just be me not being a native English speaker through.

Comment: Disclaimers are good, but clients (like users) don't read. :)

Comment: As I noted, I used this before I presented work as well. So, yes, clients did hear it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you can, do *not* send artifacts via email for them to look at without you there. A bit part of your job is presenting the work you create.

So ideally, always show the work to them first during a presentation. That way they're not as likely to jump to all sorts of conclusions prior to your explanations.

Comment: You know problem with this I've faced is that client will listen to you, but after the presentation is over they'll tell you that they need to go through it to understand it better. And then they send you a mail asking questions about the exact things you spent 30 minutes explaining and I go like oh "I told you why I did the way it is" and I have to re-explain it to them.